# Review Queue - close question help text

Tags: discussion, review

On the low quality posts review queue, expanding the help section looks like this:

[image: Low quality posts queue]

For **Close** - the reason is "if the question cannot be fixed and should be removed immediately".

But that isn't even remotely accurate. What we are really doing is putting the question "On Hold" and encouraging the author to clean up the post. The question is not removed and this isn't the spirit of what closing (on holding?) is supposed to be.

This text should be changed to (something like)

**Close** if you cannot fix the problems with the question and the author should review it before accepting answers.

Comment: Apparently just replacing "delete" with "close" isn't sufficient in the review queue.  Good thing people who aren't familiar with the system don't ever read the help text.